# Topology with No Disjoint Open Sets

Tags: general-topology, terminology

The [nested interval topology](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000044) on $(0,1)$ is the collection of open intervals $\{(0, 1- \frac{1}{n}) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 2\}$. This topology has the property that no two open sets are disjoint (they all contain the element $\frac{1}{3}$, for example).

Is there a term for a topology in which no two open sets are disjoint?

Comment: There are no such spaces because the empty set is open.

Comment: @bof: I think it was pretty clear all those years ago that the OP meant non-empty open sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such spaces are called [hyperconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space).

Comment: I don't know how I managed to overlook this one. Thanks for the prompt answer.

Comment: Hyperconnected spaces are usually defined by the much weaker condition, that no two ***nonempty*** open sets are disjoint.

Comment: @bof: Yes, sure. I think it was pretty clear that this was what the OP wanted and following the link gets you to the correct definition.

Comment: Personally, I would have asked for clarification before answering, or, if the intention was really obvios (as in this case) pointed out the correction in my answer. It would not have occurred to me to answer the presumably intended question without noting the discrepancy.